# Gradle: How to copy a list of absolute paths into a single directory

Tags: gradle, groovy

In Gradle, I'm trying to copy a list of absolute paths into a single directory, but I want to keep the last component of the absolute path as a subfolder of the destination directory.

Currently I have:

```
def copyTask = tasks.create(name: "copyFolders", type: Copy, overwrite: true) {
    from ["/sources/a-1/first", "/sources/a-3/b-1/c-1/second"]
    into "/destination"
}
```

but this results in the files contained in `/sources/foo/bar` and `/sources/one/two/three/path` being copied into `/destination`. Instead, I want `/destination` to contain both `bar` and `path` folders (with their contents inside them).

---

It should be able to handle this case correctly:

```
sources
├── a-1
│   └── fist
│       └── lorem.txt
|       └── subfolder
│           └── lorem2.txt
├── a-2
│   └── fist-b
│       └── lorem.txt
|       └── subfolder
│           └── lorem2.txt
└── a-3
    └── b-1
        └── c-1
            └── second
                └── ipsum.log
```

->

```
destination
├── first
│   └── lorem.txt
│   └── subfolder
│       └── lorem2.txt
└── path
    └── ipsum.log
```

---

Based on @szymon answer I got:

```
def copyTask = tasks.create(name: "copyToDestDir", type: Copy, overwrite: true) {
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    def fromDir = "/sources"
    def sourcePaths = ["/sources/a-1/first", "/sources/a-3/b-1/c-1/second"]
    from fileTree(fromDir).dir.listFiles()
    eachFile { copySpec ->
        def shouldBeCopied = false
        sourcePaths.find {
            if (copySpec.getFile().getCanonicalPath().startsWith(it)) {
                shouldBeCopied = true
                return true // break iteration
            }
        }
        if (shouldBeCopied) {
            String[] parts = file.path.split('/')
            copySpec.path = parts.size() > 1 ? "${parts[parts.size() - 2]}/${parts[parts.size() - 1]}" : parts[0]
        } else {
            copySpec.exclude()
        }
    }
    into destDir
}
```

but this wrongly results in:

```
destination
├── first
│   └── lorem.txt
└── subfolder
│    └── lorem2.txt
└── path
    └── ipsum.log
```

---

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try following Gradle task:

```
task copyFiles(type: Copy, overwrite: true) {
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    from fileTree("sources").dir.listFiles()
    eachFile { file ->
        String[] parts = file.path.split('/')
        file.path = parts.size() > 1 ? "${parts[parts.size() - 2]}/${parts[parts.size() - 1]}" : parts[0]
    }
    into "destDir"
}
```

The whole part happens in `eachFile {}` closure where we specify a target `file.path` - I used this imperative approach, but it can be replaced with fancy regex that keeps last folder and file name and replaces all other parts with empty string (I tried to come up with such regex but I failed).

#### How it works

My input directory looks like this:

```
sources
├── foo
│   └── bar
│       └── lorem.txt
└── one
    └── two
        └── three
            └── path
                └── ipsum.log
```

I run a task:

```
#: ./gradlew copyFiles                                                  
:copyFiles UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

And the `destDir` looks like this:

```
destDir
├── bar
│   └── lorem.txt
└── path
    └── ipsum.log
```

Tested with Gradle `2.14.1`, `3.5-rc-2` and `4.2.1`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This looks promising. What if `bar`, `path`, and their parents have sibling directories I'm not interested in?

Comment: I resolved the issue mentioned in my comment, but this solution is not working, because any subfolder of `bar` and `path` get moved to the root instead of being left inside.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved this doing this. Note that the top level `into` directive is needed or it won't work, and the nested `into` directives are relative to the top-level one.

```
def copyTask = tasks.create(name: "copyToDestDir", type: Copy, overwrite: true) {
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    def fromDir = "/sources"
    def sourcePaths = ["/sources/a-1/first", "/sources/a-3/b-1/c-1/second"]
    def destDir = "/destination"
    sourcePaths.each { sourcePath ->
        from(sourcePath) {
            into sourcePath.substring(sourcePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
        }
    }
    into destDir
    dependsOn cleanUpDestDir
}
```

Thanks to @SzymonStepniak for the inspiration.